# Не работает required при заполнении поля. Отправка писем

Tags: javascript, html, email

Есть сайт (простой одностраничник), в котором есть форма отправки "Имя" и "Телефон" на почту. Дело в том что не работает required в поле "Телефон",  в то время как в поле "Имя" всё исправно работает. Если я введу имя и нажму кнопку отправки, то письмо уйдёт на почту без телефона, а хотелось бы, что бы и в незаполненном поле "Телефон" так же выскакивала ошибка пустого поля. Пытался стандартными методами вставить Атрибут required, например:

```
<input name="user" required placeholder="Ваше имя">
```

Но ничего не помогло, видимо что то в коде блокирует. Сайт с нуля писал не я, по этому не могу разобраться в чужом коде, помогите пожалуйста.

Ниже представлю код:

```js
function checkForm(form1) {

  var $form = $(form1),
    checker = true,
    name = $("input[name='name']", $form).val(),
    phone1 = $("input[name='phone']", $form).val(),
    phone2 = $("input[name='phone2']", $form).val(),
    phone3 = $("input[name='phone3']", $form).val(),
    email = $("input[name='email']", $form).val(),
    phone3_1 = $("input[name='phone3']", $form);

  if ($form.find(".name").hasClass("required")) {
    if (!name) {
      $form.find(".name").addClass("red");
      checker = false;
    } else {
      $form.find(".name").removeClass('red');
    }
  }

  if ($form.find(".phone").hasClass("required")) {
    if (!phone1) {
      $form.find(".phone").addClass("red");
      checker = false;
    } else {
      $form.find(".phone").removeClass("red");
    }

    if (!phone2) {
      $form.find(".phone").addClass("red");
      checker = false;
    } else {
      $form.find(".phone").removeClass("red");
    }

    if (!phone3) {
      $form.find(".phone").addClass("red");
      checker = false;
    } else if (/[^0-9 -]/.test(phone3) || phone3.length < 4) {
      $form.find(".phone").addClass("red");
      checker = false;
    } else {
      $form.find(".phone").removeClass("red");
    }
  }

  if ($form.find(".email").hasClass("required")) {
    if (!email) {
      $form.find(".email").addClass("red");
      checker = false;
    } else if (!/^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z]{1,4}$/.test(email)) {
      $form.find(".email").addClass("red");
      checker = false;
    } else {
      $form.find(".email").removeClass("red");
    }
  }

  if (checker != true) {
    return false;
  }
}




$(document).ready(function() {
      var prefix = $('.prefix').val();
      var url = prefix + "respond.php";


      $('.button').click(function() {
        $('body').find('form:not(this)').children('label').removeClass('red');
        var request_url = '\n' + $('input[name="ref_url"]').val().toString().replace(/&/g, '\n');
        var utm_source = $('input[name="ref_url"]').val().match(/(?:utm_source=)(.*)(?:&utm_medium)/i);
        var utm_medium = $('input[name="ref_url"]').val().match(/(?:utm_medium=)(.*)(?:&utm_campaign)/i);
        var utm_campaign = $('input[name="ref_url"]').val().match(/(?:utm_campaign=)(.*)(?:&utm_term)/i);
        var utm_term = $('input[name="ref_url"]').val().match(/(?:utm_term=)([0-9a-zA-Zа-яА-Я%]{1,})/i);
        if (utm_source == null || utm_medium == null || utm_campaign == null || utm_term == null)
          var utms = '';
        else
          var utms = '\nutm_source=' + utm_source[1] + '\nutm_medium=' + utm_medium[1] + '\nutm_campaign=' + utm_campaign[1] + '\nutm_term=' + utm_term[1] + '\n';

        var answer = checkForm($(this).parent().get(0));
        if (answer != false) {

          var $form = $(this).parent(),
            name = $('input[name="name"]', $form).val(),
            phone = $('input[name="phone2"]', $form).val(),
            email = $('input[name="email"]', $form).val(),
            dropdown = $('select[name="dropdown"]', $form).val(),
            usluga = $('input[name="usluga"]', $form).val(),
            referer = $('input[name="referer"]', $form).val(),
            phrase = $('input[name="phrase"]', $form).val(),
            ccall = $('input[name="ccall"]', $form).val(),
            ques = $('textarea[name="ques"]', $form).val(),
            sbt = $('input[type="button"]', $form).attr("name"),
            submit = $('input[name=' + sbt + ']', $form).val();
          var ref = $('input[name="referer"]').val();
          var ref = ref + '\nutm-метки:' + request_url;
          var formname = $('input[name="formname"]').val();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            data: "dropdown=" + dropdown + "&name=" + name + "&usluga=" + usluga + "&referer=" + referer + "&phrase=" + phrase + "&ccall=" + ccall + "&phone=" + phone + "&" + sbt + "=" + submit + "&email=" + email + "&formname=" + formname + "&ref=" + ref
          }).always(function() {
            //метрики
            //ga('send', 'event', ''+sbt, ''+sbt, ''+sbt);
            thx();
          });
        }
      });
```

```html
<div class="popup" id="request">
  <div class="popup_h1">Заказать консультацию</div>
  <form>
    <label class="name left required">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="input_name" placeholder="Как Вас зовут?">
    </label>
    <br>
    <label class="phone top request">
      <input type="text" name="phone2" class="input_ph2" placeholder="+375...">
    </label>
    <select class="pes" style="    width: 433px;
    padding: 15px 18px;
    border: 0;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;    height: 52px;
    color: #808080;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: gotham;" name="dropdown" size="1">
      <option value="Удобное время для звонка">Удобное время для звонка</option>
      <option value="Сейчас">Сейчас</option>
      <option value="Через 15 минут">Через 15 минут</option>
      <option value="Через 30 минут">Через 30 минут</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input id=u2 name="usluga" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id=r2 name="referer" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id=n2 name="phrase" type="hidden" value="">
    <input name="ccall" type="hidden" value="2">

    <input name="request" type="button" class="bttn bttn2 button noselect" value="Оставить заявку на консультацию">
  </form>
</div>
```

Для Anton:

```
        var $form = $(this).parent(),
            name = $('input[name="name"]', $form).val(),
        phone1 = $("input[name='phone']", $form).val(),
        phone2 = $("input[name='phone2']", $form).val(),
        phone3 = $("input[name='phone3']", $form).val(),
            email = $('input[name="email"]', $form).val(),
            dropdown  = $('select[name="dropdown"]', $form).val(),
    usluga = $('input[name="usluga"]', $form).val(),
    referer = $('input[name="referer"]', $form).val(),
    phrase = $('input[name="phrase"]', $form).val(),
    ccall = $('input[name="ccall"]', $form).val(),
            ques = $('textarea[name="ques"]', $form).val(),
            sbt = $('input[type="button"]', $form).attr("name"),
            submit = $('input[name='+sbt+']', $form).val();
        var ref = $('input[name="referer"]').val();
        var ref = ref+'\nutm-метки:'+request_url;
        var formname = $('input[name="formname"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            data: "dropdown="+dropdown+"&name="+name+"&usluga="+usluga+"&referer="+referer+"&phrase="+phrase+"&ccall="+ccall+"&phone="+phone+"&"+sbt+"="+submit+"&email="+email+"&formname="+formname+"&ref="+ref
        }).always(function() {
            //метрики
            //ga('send', 'event', ''+sbt, ''+sbt, ''+sbt);
            thx();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

судя по коду

> `if ($form.find(".phone").hasClass("required")) {`

required ожидается в классе, а не в атрибуте

```
 <label class="phone top request required">
```

И еще, согласно коду

```
phone1 = $("input[name='phone']", $form).val(),
phone2 = $("input[name='phone2']", $form).val(),
phone3 = $("input[name='phone3']", $form).val(),
```

у Вас должно быть три инпута с именами `phone`, `phone2`, `phone3`. А у Вас только `phone2`

Если Вам нужен только один телефон, то модифицируйте код

> `phone1 = $("input[name='phone']", $form).val(),
>       phone2 = $("input[name='phone2']", $form).val(),
>       phone3 = $("input[name='phone3']", $form).val(),
>       ............
>       if ($form.find(".phone").hasClass("required")) {
>       if (!phone1) {
>         $form.find(".phone").addClass("red");
>         checker = false;
>       } else {
>         $form.find(".phone").removeClass("red");
>       }
>       if (!phone2) {
>         $form.find(".phone").addClass("red");
>         checker = false;
>       } else {
>         $form.find(".phone").removeClass("red");
>       }
>       if (!phone3) {
>         $form.find(".phone").addClass("red");
>         checker = false;
>       } else if (/[^0-9 -]/.test(phone3) || phone3.length < 4) {
>         $form.find(".phone").addClass("red");
>         checker = false;
>       } else {
>         $form.find(".phone").removeClass("red");
>       }
>   }`

на такой

```
phone = $("input[name='phone']", $form).val(),
............
if ($form.find(".phone").hasClass("required")) {
  if (!phone) {
    $form.find(".phone").addClass("red");
    checker = false;
  } else {
    $form.find(".phone").removeClass("red");
  }
}
```

и соответственно измените имя инпута

```
 <input type="text" name="phone" class="input_ph2" placeholder="+375...">
```

Comment: Использовал Ваш совет, теперь и правда в поле "Телефон" показывается, что поле не заполнено, но даже когда я ввожу цифры или буквы, оно так и остаётся не заполненным, соответственно письмо не отправляется.

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов доуточнил свой ответ

Comment: Ничего не поменялось - показывается, что поле не заполнено, но даже когда я ввожу цифры или буквы, оно так и остаётся не заполненным, соответственно письмо не отправляется

Comment: Еще раз - у Вас должно быть **три** поля с именами `phone`, `phone2`, `phone3`

Comment: Я добавил в вопрос, вконце, код который у меня получился, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов И, что изменилось? Ну смотрите сами,у Вас заполняется три переменных `phone1`, `phone2`, `phone3`. Инпут у Вас только один `<input type="text" name="phone2" class="input_ph2" placeholder="+375...">`, соответственно две переменных `phone1` и `phone3` остаются пустыми. Отсюда и требование заполнить телефон. Либо добавьте еще два инпута, либо уберите две переменных

Comment: Я понял про что вы говорите. А как? Где убрать две переменных?

Comment: я еще раз доуточнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, у меня всё получилось, с Вашей помощью.